# TimePickerDialog auto dismiss on set

Tags: android, view, timepicker, dismiss

how do i disable from the TimePickerDialog to dismiss when press set ?

i need to check if the value is good , if it's no i don't want it to be dismiss .

```
mTimePicker.setCancelable(true);
```

but i do want the user to be able to dismiss with cancel...

```
    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,
                                int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                            if(condition){
                            mTimePicker.dismiss();

                               }else{
                            showMessage();
                                    }

                        }
                    }, hour, minute, false);// Yes 24 hour time
            mTimePicker.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_time));

            mTimePicker.show();
```

Comment: And what is problem?

Comment: if the value is good, what does this mean??

Comment: i want to chose when onTimeSet if to dismiss the time picker or not . in this code it will be dismissed when you press set . the only solution is to call  mTimePicker.show(); again ?

Answer (score 1):

I'll just drop a sample code of [Jesus Dimrix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1951967/jesus-dimrix)'s "only solution" to call mTimepicker.show() again.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
       @Override
       public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
           if(hourOfDay > 12){
               timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,this,hourOfDay,minute,true);
               timePickerDialog.show();
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Must be less than 12",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }else{
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,hourOfDay + ":" + minute,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
       }, hour, minute, true);
       timePickerDialog.show();
```

I hope someone else could give a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

use any one:

```
mTimePicker.cancel();
```

or

```
mTimePicker.dismiss();
```